# Use Azure SQL Always Encrypted in Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I tried to use Always encrypted feature of Azure SQL DB. I successfully implemented it in .net core 3.1 web application with Azure Key Vault. But when I try to implement same in Azure Functions it says

> 'SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for
>   'RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders'

What is the reason for this? and
What are the Solutions or Other Options do I have to use Always encrypted feature in Azure Functions?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/111

Comment: I refer this issue but according to that.it is possible now to do this in .NET core 2.1. And I did it too with .NET core 3.1 web app. but I can't do same in .NET core 3.1 azure functions. I am getting error msg as I mentioned in the question

Comment: @S.Sethsara Could you please tell me which sdk you use?

Comment: I think I found the reason .this function work on Microsoft.NetCore.App framework but not working on .NetStandard.Library framework.

Comment: @JimXu I used this package on Azure functions(.net core 3.1) is it what you asked?
"Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider -Version 1.1.1"

Comment: The sdk `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider -Version 1.1.1`:https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider/ depends on `.netcore2.1` or `NETFramework4.6`. So I think we cannot use the sdk in NetStandard.Library project.